# Send a binary file though serial terminal

Tags: file-copy, serial-console

I have a question related to the serial terminal. I have a Linux computer and I connect to an ARM mini-computer running debian with `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`. From there, I can login and type commands.

That means I can virtually transfer any text file, by creating a file on the ARM through the serial terminal, opening the file in the Linux computer and copy all the text to the opened terminal.

Now, I would like to transfer binary data. My ARM computer doesn't have access to internet and thus, can't install packages. That includes `minicom`, sadly. Besides, it doesn't have `rz` out of the box.

In summary, I can easily transfer everything that is text. Now, I would like to copy a binary file through it. How can it be done?

P.s.: This question extend [Send a binary file through serial terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545339/send-a-binary-file-through-serial-terminal/545367), with a bit more constraints.

Comment: Can your ARM system read USB storage? Or does it have any form of networking at all?

Comment: What tools *does* the ARM computer have? Does it have `uudecode`, `base64` or any similar tool capable of decoding an ASCII-encoded binary back to binary form? Or a `perl`, `python` or some other powerful script interpreter that could be used to *make* one?

Comment: Yes, I have python, and I was considering using it to do such function. But I was hoping there is an out of the box tool for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `shar` from GNU `sharutils` to make a text file out of the binary file, then copy and paste that text file as you’ve been doing. The text file will be a shell script which will recover the original binary file when executed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Sharutils

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you have on the ARM box.  Do you have `uuencode`?  `base64`?  `perl`?

Basically you convert the binary to ASCII using some wrapper program, send the ASCII file to the remote machine, then unwrap it back to the binary.

So, for example

```
uuencode myfile > myfile.uue
```

Now send myfile.uue to the remote end

Then on the remote end

```
uudecode myfile.uue
```

There are many ways of wrapping binary into ASCII; `uuencode` and `base64` are two common methods.  Without knowing what you have on the machine it's impossible to know what method would be best for you.

Once you've worked out how to do that *then* you could use this method to transfer a better program such as `minicom` or `rz` and use that.  Basically use the ASCII wrapping to "bootstrap" a reliable transfer process.